# Understanding「知見ばかりだった」

Tags: grammar, meaning

A person is commenting about his experience working with two well known writers:

> あのニ人は創作能力で言えば日本で指折りのクリエイターだ
>
> 俺じゃ逆立ちしても出てこない知見ばかりだったよ

I have trouble understanding the 知見ばかりだった part. I guess 知見 refers to a person who watch and learn? What nuance does ばかりだった add? Also why it is in past tense?

Comment: 知見 refers to (specialized) knowledge or insights gained from experience or direct observation, something that cannot be easily obtained from textbooks. For example, when a researcher or an engineer failed in an experiment but gained some insight from it, that is referred to as "有意義な知見が得られた".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[知見](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%9F%A5%E8%A6%8B/#je-47726) is knowledge itself rather than person.

Whatever the topic is, the speaker is saying that all the knowledge shared by those two people is not something the speaker can easily come up with. In the particular context, it could be understood as ideas proposed by the two people.

ばかり is used in the standard way ([#2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A/#je-60083)), meaning *all/most of the ideas (were something that wouldn't come out from me)*.

だった is used because it is referring to the past experience (I assume the two people are not present in the conversation).